# Как можно упросить выражение?

Tags: javascript

```
$(function(){
    $(".mini_news .short_news:nth-child(3) .full_link_open").click(function(){
        $(".mini_news .short_news:nth-child(3)").toggleClass("open_news");
    });
})

$(function(){
    $(".mini_news .short_news:nth-child(4) .full_link_open").click(function(){
        $(".mini_news .short_news:nth-child(4)").toggleClass("open_news");
    });
})

$(function(){
    $(".mini_news .short_news:nth-child(5) .full_link_open").click(function(){
        $(".mini_news .short_news:nth-child(5)").toggleClass("open_news");
    });
})
```

Comment: В зависимости от того, что вы хотите. Что у вас в `html` и что конкретно с ней хотите сделать? Нужно более подробное описание

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Навскидку, этот код можно сократить так:

```
$(function(){
    function assigner(n) {
        var ref = '.mini_news .short_news:nth-child(' +n +')';
        $(ref +' .full_link_open').on('click', function(){
            $(ref).toggleClass("open_news");
        });
    }
    [3,4,5].map(assigner);
});
```

Чтобы предложить что-то лучше, хорошо бы видеть весь код.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".mini_news .short_news:nth-child(3) .full_link_open,.mini_news .short_news:nth-child(4) .full_link_open,.mini_news .short_news:nth-child(5) .full_link_open").click(function(){
    $(this).parent().toggleClass("open_news");
});
```

Comment: Да, но только он применяет их к .mini_news .short_news:nth-child(Номер) .full_link_open, а надо к .mini_news .short_news:nth-child(Номер)